# getting complete null values in merged column in bigquery after writing code for merging two data frames in cloud function

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm created a Google Cloud Platform Function for merging two data frames on the basis of column but as the output in bigquery ,i am getting null values in merged column but in my dataset there is no null values.

here is my code

```
cars=pd.read_csv('gs://' + event['bucket'] +'/' + file_name)
# Loading a new sheet as a dataframe

reg_code = pd.read_csv('gs://cars_bucket1/region1.csv')

# Decoding VIN in cars dataframe

cars["Code_VIN"] = cars["VIN"].apply(lambda x:x[:2])

# Merge dataframes

cars = cars.merge(reg_code, how = "inner", on = "Code_VIN")

cars.to_gbq(f'batchProject.'+'Adding region'+'-'+table_name,
        project_id='batchproject-410113' ,
        if_exists = 'replace'
        )
```

Below I am attaching the bigquery table that I got as output in this table the region column is completely null but i was expecting that my two Dataframes will merged on the basis of VIN code and a new column will be created which have region of cars.

[image: Bigquery table]